# Fermat's Last Theorem - Variation with arithmetically descending exponents

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, diophantine-equations

Are there solution(s) to the following variant of Fermat's Last Theorem in the positive integers?

$$
a^n + b^{n-i} = c^{n-2i}
$$

<strike>I haven't been able to identify any trivial solutions. To my (mathematically untrained) eye, it seems obvious that at least $n > 2i$ must hold.</strike>

Zev Chonoles noted in early commenting that $n=3$, $i=1$, and $a,b$ arbitrary provides a class of trivial solutions and, indeed, such trivial solutions exist for any $n-2i=1$.  So! Are there any solutions to the above equation in the positive integers, where $n-2i>1$?

---

The above was inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419038/opposite-of-fermats-last-theorem) question, and in particular the last portion of Ypnypn's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419038/opposite-of-fermats-last-theorem/1419252#1419252) to it:

> We can also note that
>   $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{z-1}{a^k} = {a^z-1\over a-1} < a^z
> $$
>
> Meaning, even if we added all the exponents of $a$ less than $z$, we still wouldn't reach $a^z$.

Essentially, it pointed to the question, "What *could* one reach with sums of exponents, if not 'all the way to $a^z$'"?  Any corresponding variant of the original [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419038/opposite-of-fermats-last-theorem) is just a subset of the problem posed in that original question, so I went straight to the above form.

Comment: There's plenty of trivial solutions with $n=3$, $i=1$, and $a,b$ arbitrary.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Ha! Indeed. Are there trivial solutions any time $n-2i=1$?

Comment: Yup, that seems to be the case. Of course, it's your prerogative to disallow such cases.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yep - this is what tends to happen when I post on Math.SE -- it takes several iterations to iron out the trivialities that actual mathematicians see right away.

Comment: @ZevChonoles What think ye now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\gcd(n,2i)=1$. Given any $x$, $y$, let $x^n+y^{n-i}=w$. Then for any $r$ we have $$x^nw^{rn(n-i)}+y^{n-i}w^{rn(n-i)}=w^{1+rn(n-i)}$$ which is to say $$(xw^{r(n-i)})^n+(yw^{rn})^{n-i}=w^{1+rn(n-i)}$$ Since $n$ (and, thus, $n-i$) is prime to $n-2i$, we can choose $r$ such that $1+rn(n-i)=(n-2i)s$ for some integer $s$, and so we have a solution of $a^n+b^{n-i}=c^{n-2i}$.

Much more interesting would be to find solutions with $a,b,c$ pairwise coprime. I suspect that all the work that has been done on the general $a^r+b^s=c^t$ since Wiles-Taylor has already settled this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the simplest one I could find in a few minutes was $100^4 + 500^3 = 15000^2$.

Comment: $1^4+2^3=3^2$ is simpler.

Comment: Ha!! Got me. Though I did see that one and discarded it.

Comment: Another example: $n=6$, $i=2$, $3^6+6^4=45^2$.

Comment: John or @JuliánAguirre, would you be willing to lay out your thought process in finding these?  (If there was one, that is... as opposed to just fiddling/free-searching.)

Comment: It was a search with Mathematica.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Ahh, brute force. :-)

Comment: I just noticed that 100+125=225 and figured I could tweak a 4th power in there. Not too helpful either I guess.

Comment: Julián's uses the well known identity of sqares $3^4( 3^2+4^2)=3^4(5^2)$ Perhaps such an ansatz allows a structure for more solutions...